# Xcode 6.1 Simulator - Location Issues

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode6, core-location

I have created a location based app, and it works fine on the device. But on the simulator there appears to be sporadic issues where the location services just stops working. Everyday for the past few days, I have worked on the app using the simulator without issues, however when I come back into work the next day and start the app again, I am getting the usual error

```
didFailWithError: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"
```

This happens to every location app I have, I have a few custom code examples I have  I use for reference to check the issue is not just happening to my application. So this confirms that it is not a coding issue

Usually I can fix the issue, after a few attempts of resetting simulator, deleting derived data, double checking I have setup a simulated location under edit scheme. It usually takes a few attempts of trying this various techniques to get it working. But today I cannot get it working at all on the simulator.

Now I am sure after playing about with for longer, I will eventually get this working again on the simulator, but I would like to know the root cause of this issue. I am getting tired of every morning, repeating this routine of resetting sim, deleting data, as it is wasting time that could be spent actually coding.

Is this an issue with the Xcode 6.1 simulator? Why does this seem to happen quite often and does anyone else have a better solution to this issue?

Comment: File a radar with a sample project and reproduction steps at http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

I have filed a bug report with Apple as suggested by Jeremy Huddleston Sequoia. However for the time being, if anyone else has this issue, the only work around I have found to truly fix this is, first reset the simulator, secondly delete the derived data folder, then finally reset the mac. It is frustrating, but every day this week I have had this issue, and for the time being, this is the only solution I have found that seems to work, well sometimes. Hope this helps if anyone else is having this problem. If Apple respond to my error report, I will update my answer

Answer (score -1):

it happens often to me and use xCode 6.1.

Usually Cmd + Shift + K, which is about the equivalent of resetting the simulator , I can make it work.

Other times , change device , launch the iPhone 5 on the simulator and on the iPhone 6 and then I go after ...

Strange thing ... I agree with you that it may be some sort of bug or poorly procedures initiated by the compiler.
Also because then once part after is always the simulator

Comment: Meant to say I am using xCode 6.1, resetting the simulator only sometimes works, same with deleting derived data. I am hoping to find a quicker solution. Also changing device can actually cause the issue as well. I was debugging on iPhone 6 sim, then swapped to 6Plus sim, and it wasn't working on that either. So swapped back to iPhone 6 sim, and stopped working on that too. Took me nearly an hour of playing about with xCode before getting location services to work again on simulator. I am hoping to find a more concrete solution

Comment: Sometimes it is convenient to use public external framework , so as to have a cross platform Independently from bugs , especially for services which normally are not very stable since xcode .

Comment: Shift command k has nothing to do with resetting the simulator or location services.  That just toggles the hardware keyboard.

Comment: is not Shift + Command + K but... Command + Shift + K..check your process